# Why is Kickass Torrents banned in my browser?

Tags: software, torrent

I am trying to access Kickass Torrents, but getting warning from the browser like this:

> Reported Unwanted Software Page!
>
> This web page at kat.cr has been reported to contain unwanted software and has been blocked based on your security preferences.
>
> Unwanted software pages try to install software that can be deceptive and affect your system in unexpected ways.

Now we all know Kickass Torrents contains harmful programs, that's nothing new, so why the ban now all of a sudden?

It's been the case since last week. Sometimes it's available sometimes it's not. Any way to access this site?

Comment: Try other browsers.

Comment: Now we all know Kickass Torrents contains harmful programs, that's nothing new, so why the ban now all of a sudden? ///// Very wrong, torrent file containing meta info of harmful program is different than serving /forcing user to download or install harmful program by using some blackhat technique on website, this is more serious issue for regular surfers as they can get easily infected without having to download .torrent file . so the warning is there to protect users . FF and chrome doesnt care what you download using torrent file in torrent client.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this has been blocked by both FireFox and Google due to malicious programs being hosted on the website. This doesn't appear to be intentional distribution of the malware as identified in the below link. This warning might not be present in another browser, such as IE. However, these warnings are normally present for a reason and should generally be followed.

http://www.spamfighter.com/News-19900-KAT-Becomes-Unsafe-So-Firefox-Chrome-Disable-the-Website.htm

> For separate browsers, warnings too have been slightly different, however, the main message was the same Users of Chrome got the warning that hackers who controlled kat.cr were likely for duping victims into planting software which was harmful during browsing (like altering the homepage else displaying additional advertisements on the websites accessed), while users of Firefox got the warning that the page open on the kat.cr site reportedly had undesirable software that had gotten disrupted depending upon the user's security preferences.

Answer (score 1):

1) Click on Details in the lower left hand corner of the page.

2) Click the visit this site link.

[image: Picture of issue]